# Format data for Highcharts chart

Tags: php, highcharts

I'm trying to create Highcharts chart from mysql, I have code like this:

```
 xAxis: {
   categories: [<?php  echo  implode($column, ','); ?>]
 }
```

and column has been grabbed from mysql:

```
  $column = array();
  $column[] = $row['blabla'];
```

What I am actually getting is:

```
 xAxis: {
   categories: [data1,data2,data3,data4,data5]
 }
```

but it has to be like this:

```
 xAxis: {
   categories: ["data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"]
 }
```

How can I format it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will format your array of strings as a JSON object, including escaping, etc., which can then be passed into HighCharts with the following:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: <?php echo json_encode($column); ?>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work too.

> categories: ["<\?php  echo  implode($column, '","'); ?>"]

Answer (score -1):

Just input the data with the quotes.

`$column[] = '"'.$row['blabla'].'"';`

Comment: You'll run into issues with strings containing `"`.