# how to show PHP array in jQuery alert?

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

In my php project I have an array and I need to use array's values as the column of the charts. I'm using  [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) for creating column chart and highcharts using javascript.
how can I read array from php and use in javascript as column of my chart.
thanks.

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) baby!

Comment: just make your php array into javascript array by echo() and iterating it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format data for Highcharts chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390714/format-data-for-highcharts-chart)

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array('hi','684','2');
echo "var array = ". json_encode($array) . ";\n";
```

As Christian says, if you want only the format change, you should only do

```
$array = array('hi','684','2');
json_encode($array);
```

Comment: If he would use jQuery ajax to request this data as json, it would fail. You should only return the json encoded array, nothing else.

Comment: Mhmhm it's possible, yes, I'll add it as another option because I understood the question as a php-javascript conversion and this includes variable definition to me.

Comment: yeee. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390714/format-data-for-highcharts-chart) help me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax request to the php file where your data is located.
jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET'
  url: 'pathtomyphpfile'
  success: function(msg){
    var data = msg;
  }
});
```

Php:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```